# Adding data from all datasources to display only the sum value in barchart of thingsboard widget

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, widget, thingsboard

Following is the JS script that I'm trying to modify (time series):

```
self.onInit = function() {
    self.ctx.flot = new TbFlot(self.ctx, 'bar');   
    
    console.log("console",self.ctx.data)
}

self.onDataUpdated = function() {
    
   
    //console.log("console",self.ctx.$scope.data[0]) //
    self.ctx.flot.update();
}

self.onLatestDataUpdated = function() {
    self.ctx.flot.latestDataUpdate();
}

self.onResize = function() {
    self.ctx.flot.resize();
}

self.onEditModeChanged = function() {
    self.ctx.flot.checkMouseEvents();
}

self.onDestroy = function() {
    self.ctx.flot.destroy();
}

self.typeParameters = function() {
    return {
        hasAdditionalLatestDataKeys: true
    };
}
```

I plan to add one more data source by duplicating the first element:

```
self.ctx.data.push(self.ctx.data[0]);
```

And later sum data from all the sources to update the data at the duplicated element and finally plot this value only in the barchart.

However, I get the following error just after duplicating the element and running:

[image]

[image]

I can see that data being updated in the chart but I get an error before  I can do the mathematics. Following is the console log before and after duplicating the data.

[image]

[image]

Is my approach correct? Shall I update the HTML template and use `$scope` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using: self.ctx.data.push(angular.copy(self.ctx.data[0]));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't there an issue with the way you create your duplicated data?

```
self.ctx.data.push(self.ctx.data[0]);
```

As shown in the logs, `self.ctx.data[0]` is an object. This means that duplicating this way, your data[0] and your new last element are linked and identical. When you modify data[0] it updates the last one and vice versa.
You should better create a new object. Be careful of nested objects too.